# my sqlite3 DB doesn't show column values in device but it does in simulator

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, ios-simulator

My DB is not getting copied over to my device, but it does to the simulator.

Here is what I am doing:

Create a new sqllite3 db from terminal:

```
sqlite> create table myTable (id integer primary key, name text);
sqlite> insert into myTable (name) values ('john');
sqlite> select * from myTable;
1|john
```

This creates a db in this path: users/John/iosApp.db

Then I close the terminal and copy that db to my xamarin project and set its buildAction to 'content'.

Here is my model:

```
[Table("myTable")]
public class MyTable
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrementAttribute, Column("id")]
    public int ID {get; set;}

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I do this to copy the db to the Document folder:

```
string pathToDatabase = "iosApp.db";
userPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), pathToDatabase);
File.Delete (userPath); // delete first and copy next
File.Copy (pathToDatabase, userPath);
var myDB = new SQLiteConnection (userPath);
MyTable myTable = myDB.Get<MyTable> (1);
```

then I run the app and I set a breaking point after the last line in the code above and I hover over the myTable:

if I am using the simulator, I see the schema and value of 1 for ID and 'john' for Name.

if I am using the device, I see the schema but 0 value for ID and null for Name!

Looking at the path when I am using the device, points to this: 
"/private/var/mobile/Applications/277749D4-C5CC-4BF4-8EF0-23B23833FCB1/Documents/iosApp.db"

I loaded the files in using iFunBox and the db file is there with the exact size

I have tried all the following:

- Clean All in the project
- Rebuild All
- removed the 'debug' folder from the project
- restarted Xamarin
- and even restart the machine

But still the same behavior, what else should I try to be able to see the values of ID and Name?

my sdk version is attached[image]

UPDATE:

After a lot of changes and cleaning up, I managed to display the value of all columns except the identity column displayed as 0. Puzzled, I went back to the xamarin sample project: http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/data/sqlite/create_a_database_with_sqlitenet/
it displayed the value of the identity correctly.
Trying to bring in similar code to my project, but no success.
To role out the possibility of version issue, I went and downloaded the latest sqlite from this link:
http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net/true

The same behavior... I created a whole new page in my project, used the references the sample used and only has the code to create a sample table. Same behavior, the identity value is displayed in the other project but not mine. This leads me to conclude that there is something completely is wacky in my project. Now I am considering creating a whole new project and move my files to the new one after making sure first that the piece of being able to see the value of my id in my model shown up. Stay toned, I will make sure to update this thread.

If you have any pointers, please share them

Comment: Use Organizer to download the files from the device and then open the db file (in a command window) with the sqlite3 command.  Dump your data there and see what you have.

Comment: Great suggestion. I couldn't download the files using the organizer (download is disabled), but I did it with the ifunbox. The table in the device doesn't have the id column. Somehow the simulator db does have the id column but the device doesn't.

Comment: When you update your DB on the Mac, you generally need to delete the app on the phone (or simulator) before you reinstall, so that the DB copy logic will kick in.

Comment: i started a new example with a new db. I tested the code in the simulator first. I can see my values of my only row just fine (the id and name). Then I tested in the device, the values didn't show. So, I went and verified that A. the db is there in the documents folder by using iFunBox and B. I brought the db and opened it and the values are there. I tried removing the app from the device and retested, but still not working... this line still results into empty row:
    MyTable myTable = myDB.Get<MyTable> ("SELECT * FROM myTable where id = 1;"); the weird thing is it knows the count is 1 row!

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about how Xamarin handles the DB, so I can't help you.  Do double check the sequence you're using to access the DB -- there are several different "schemes" (eg, compiled statements or not), and if you intermingle them you often get bogus results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution to my problem, but I found an alternate method to create the DB that turns out to be even nicer than the original one.
One important thing to note is that in the original problem (details above), the DB code was working for months since I started developing the application. I don't know when it started behaving badly, but I suspect it was due to the download of the new Xamarin 3.0. I can't think of any other reason.

So, to solve my issue, There are two main things I did:

1. I followed this link on how to create DB and tables and do CRUD operations: http://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/sqlite-net/true
   This method seems to be the newest way to create DB. It was: published on
   June 24, 2014. It has an SQLite.dll, whereas my previous solution was using a SQLite.cs file. So, now I am creating my DB now at runtime.
2. Something didn't work still with the new method. It was giving me an object null exception error. I didn't spend much time investigating about it. When I provided values for my primary key and identity values, the error went away. Actually, this could have been the solution to my previous problem. I would have tried providing the identity values against the old code, if I am not already happier with the new method.

   I hope this helps someone.